# How to move views like circular motion without in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation

I want to move views like circular motion. I did this with animation but I could not click views while playing animation. I tried OnTouch,OnClick or everything for detect click views. Then I decision to try another way for move views. Is there any way for that? I haven't XML or code for that yet. So I can't share code. I'm just starting this feature. If you have different detect click way while playing animation, I can try that. Here to my codes about move view with 'animation'

```
    anim = new CircularRotateAnimation(imageView, 500);
    anim.setDuration(16000);
    anim.setRepeatCount(10);
    anim.setRepeatMode(1);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

---

```
class CircularRotateAnimation extends Animation {

private View view;              // view you want to animate
private float cx, cy;           // center x,y position of circular path
private float prevX, prevY;     // previous x,y position of image during animation
private float r;                // radius of circle
private float prevDx, prevDy;


/**
 * @param view - View that will be animated
 * @param r - radius of circular path
 */
public CircularRotateAnimation(View view, float r){
    this.view = view;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    // calculate position of image center
    int cxImage = width / 2;
    int cyImage = height / 2;
    cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
    cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

    // set previous position to center
    prevX = cx;
    prevY = cy;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    if(interpolatedTime == 0){
        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(prevDx, prevDy);
        return;
    }

    float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;
    float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

    // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
    float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
    float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));


    float dx = prevX - x;
    float dy = prevY - y;

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;

    prevDx = dx;
    prevDy = dy;

    //applying the circular animation
    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `setTranslationX` and `setTranslationY` instead of `matrix.translate`

Comment: Thats timing.. I just developed another game feature with translationX and I can click to views after animation. I though "okay I find out" and i checked this issue. Thanks for help by the way.